# group table with 1st Column of one Row and 2nd Column of lastRow

Tags: mysql

I am Stuck With Mysql Query and don't even know if it is possible or not.

I have the Following Table

[image]

And I want to Group `pstatus` in a way that startdnt column contains the first row value and enddnt contain the **last** row value of the group. Final result will look like this

[image]

so for with this query i'm able to obtain following results

```
SELECT pstatus,startdnt,enddnt,sum(Datediff(enddnt,startdnt)) as days  FROM status  GROUP by pstatus ORDER BY startdnt
```

[image]

Please note pstatus (b) may be repeat `n` number of times.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Which are you really looking for: the dates from the first and last rows or the max and min dates?

Comment: do you need to join only rows with the same enddnt and startdnt? there might be some overlapping intervals?

Comment: @G-Nugget you are right first row date is the min and last row dat is max

Comment: @fthiella i don't want to join this, consider it a simple table in which differnt status and its starting and ending dates are being added. a status might repeat and i want to group by status with sum of its days.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT pstatus,min(startdnt) as StartDate,max(enddnt)  as EndDate ...
```